# Changing GeoJSON key name

Tags: python, geojson, python-3

I have a multi-level GeoJSON file and I need to create a new geometry field within it that is a copy of the old geometry field but with a different key name.  The new geometry field would exist in the properties section of the GeoJSON.  I've tried a few different methods in Python but I keep getting an invalid GeoJSON.  Below is an example GeoJSON file.

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
 "crs": {
     "type": "name", 
     "properties": {
         "name": "EPSG:4269"}},
 "features": [{
      'type': 'Feature',
      'id': 1,
      'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
       'coordinates': [[[-122.49195406899997, 37.703511726000045],
         [-122.48671922899996, 37.703525668000054],
         [-122.48671886499994, 37.703578453000034]]]},
      'properties': {'OBJECTID': 1,
       'key1': 'item1',
       'key2': 87,
       'shape_Length': 0.025794070246599403,
       'shape_Area': 3.7520109384232215e-05,
       'Polyline_Count': 22,
       'SUM_shape_Length': 0.0158352870070439,
       'Total_Miles': 1.03803516533877}},
    {'type': 'Feature',
      'id': 2,
      'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
       'coordinates': [[[-122.47670391799994, 37.70354855800008],
         [-122.46908111099998, 37.70356779300005],
         [-122.47670391799994, 37.70354855800008]]]},
      'properties': {'OBJECTID': 2,
       'key1': 'item1',
       'key2': 176,
       'shape_Length': 0.02483662298661403,
       'shape_Area': 3.551651638576507e-05,
       'Polyline_Count': 45,
       'SUM_shape_Length': 0.0263386544389041,
       'Total_Miles': 1.56305232720018}}]
 }
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?  Which "properties" section are you attempting to append to?  [The spec says a FeatureCollection cannot contain a "properties" member](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-7.1), it would have to be within the properties for the features (and why would you want to do that?)

Answer (score 3):

Your input GeoJSON is invalid (copy paste it in https://geojsonlint.com). You can't expect a valid GeoJSON output from a bad input. So, first, you should replace all single quotes with double quotes. `crs` property is not in the specification so it has been removed. You also need to close the polygon: the end point should be the same as the start point (see the diff content that shows changed made).

```
--- a/tmp/after-correction.json
+++ b/tmp/before-correction.json
@@ -1,11 +1,5 @@
 {
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
-  "crs": {
-    "type": "name",
-    "properties": {
-      "name": "EPSG:4269"
-    }
-  },
   "features": [
     {
       "type": "Feature",
@@ -25,6 +19,10 @@
             [
               -122.48671886499994,
               37.703578453000034
+            ],
+            [
+              -122.49195406899997,
+              37.703511726000045
             ]
           ]
         ]
@@ -55,6 +53,10 @@
               -122.46908111099998,
               37.70356779300005
             ],
+            [
```

The resulting JSON should be

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -122.49195406899997,
              37.703511726000045
            ],
            [
              -122.48671922899996,
              37.703525668000054
            ],
            [
              -122.48671886499994,
              37.703578453000034
            ],
            [
              -122.49195406899997,
              37.703511726000045
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": 1,
        "key1": "item1",
        "key2": 87,
        "shape_Length": 0.025794070246599403,
        "shape_Area": 3.7520109384232215e-05,
        "Polyline_Count": 22,
        "SUM_shape_Length": 0.0158352870070439,
        "Total_Miles": 1.03803516533877
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 2,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -122.47670391799994,
              37.70354855800008
            ],
            [
              -122.46908111099998,
              37.70356779300005
            ],
            [
              -122.47670391799994,
              37.70354855800008
            ],
            [
              -122.47670391799994,
              37.70354855800008
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": 2,
        "key1": "item1",
        "key2": 176,
        "shape_Length": 0.02483662298661403,
        "shape_Area": 3.551651638576507e-05,
        "Polyline_Count": 45,
        "SUM_shape_Length": 0.0263386544389041,
        "Total_Miles": 1.56305232720018
      }
    }
  ]
}
```